# What is the composition of inversions in two concentric circles?

Tags: geometry

First, I don't really understand what the question is asking.
Second, if it is asking for the inversion of two concentric circles, I believe the answer to be two non-intersecting circles.  I've looked this up and several times I get information about mobius transformations.  But I don't understand this.  Can someone please explain.

Comment: Concentric means "same center".

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be concentric circles, and we can assume that their center is the origin. Consider the two inversions, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ *through* the given circles $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Can you write up the image of an arbitrary vector $x\ne 0$ under $\phi_1,\ \phi_2$ using the radii $r_1$ and $r_2$? 
If you have that, what will $\phi_2(\phi_1(x))$ give?